# Hive doesn't identify manually created folders as partitions

Tags: hive

I conducted an experiment. I have an external table and partitioned it by year,month,day,hour. If I use INSERT OVERWRITE and specify certain partition for the data to go to, it ends up creating appropriate folder structure. e.g.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE default.testtable PARTITION(year = 2016, month = 7, day=29, hour=18)
SELECT tbl.c1 FROM  (select 'Test' as c1) as tbl;
```

This table has only one string column but that's not very important.

So the above statement creates appropriate folder structure. But if I try to manually create similar structure and fire SELECT query, hive doesn't return data in manually created folders. In terms of structure, I made sure manually created folders look exactly the same as that of auto created folders with a 0 size file at every level of hierarchy. Is it because whenever we insert data to specific partition, Hive creates (if it doesn't exist) that partition and also stores the partition information in its metastore? Because that is the only thing that would be bypassed if I create folder structure manually.

Answer (score 1):

I just now figured out that merely by manually creating a folder won't make Hive start treating it as a partition. I would have to force Hive treat it as partition using ALTER TABLE  ADD PARTITION statement:-

```
ALTER TABLE default.testtable ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION  (year = 2016, month = 7, day=29, hour = 18);
```

After this if I fire select statement on the table, I am able to see the manually created data in that folder location.